# How to collect list of tuples into one tuple in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I think this should be a no brainer, but I'm kinda lost. If I have a list of tuples:

```
l = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

how do I put all the values from the tuples into one list so that the result is this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I guess I need to use list comprehensions, but I'm unsure how.. All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import itertools

l = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]

print list(itertools.chain(*l))
```

or

```
print list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l))



#output =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: `.chain(*l)` is exactly what `chain.from_iterable(l)` is meant for (and should be prefered)...

Comment: You can also try this way:
`list = []
for x in l:
    for y in x:
        list.append(y)`